# Azure ML model to a container instance, call to the model fails when using the code provided in the "Consume" section of the endpoint (Python and C#)

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

After deploying an Azure ML model to a container instance, call to the model fails when using the code provided in the "Consume" section of the endpoint (Python and C#).

I have trained a model in Azure Auto-ML and deployed the model to a container instance.

**Now when I am try to use the Python code provided in the Endpoint's "Consume" section I get the following error:**

```
The request failed with status code: 502
Content-Length: 55
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2022 12:32:07 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
X-Ms-Request-Id: 768c2eb5-10f3-4e8a-9412-3fcfc0f6d648
X-Ms-Run-Function-Failed: True
Connection: close

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6eeff158e915> in <module>
48 # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
49 print(error.info())
---> 50 print(json.loads(error.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore')))

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/init.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
352 parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
353 parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
355 if cls is None:
356 cls = JSONDecoder

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
337
338 """
--> 339 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
340 end = _w(s, end).end()
341 if end != len(s):

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
355 obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
356 except StopIteration as err:
--> 357 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
358 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**If I use C# code provided in the Endpoint's "Consume" section I get the following error:**

```
The request failed with status code: BadGateway
Connection: keep-alive
X-Ms-Request-Id: 5c3543cf-29ac-46a3-a9fb-dcb6a0041b08
X-Ms-Run-Function-Failed: True
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2022 12:38:32 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

**The Python code I am using:**

```
 import urllib.request
 import json
 import os
 import ssl
    
 def allowSelfSignedHttps(allowed):
     # bypass the server certificate verification on client side
     if allowed and not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None):
         ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    
 allowSelfSignedHttps(True) # this line is needed if you use self-signed certificate in your scoring service.
    
 data = {
     "Inputs": {
         "data":
         [
             {
                 "SaleDate": "2022-02-08T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "OfferingGroupId": "0",
                 "week_of_year": "7",
                 "month_of_year": "2",
                 "day_of_week": "1"
             },
         ]
     },
     "GlobalParameters": {
         "quantiles": "0.025,0.975"
     }
 }
    
 body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
    
 url = 'http://4a0427c2-30d4-477e-85f5-dfdfdfdfdsfdff623f.uksouth.azurecontainer.io/score'
 api_key = '' # Replace this with the API key for the web service
 headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key)}
    
 req = urllib.request.Request(url, body, headers)
    
 try:
     response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    
     result = response.read()
     print(result)
 except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
     print("The request failed with status code: " + str(error.code))
    
     # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
     print(error.info())
     print(json.loads(error.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore')))
```

**The C# code I have tried**:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Net.Http.Headers;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
 namespace MLModelAPICall
 {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait();
         }
    
         static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService()
         {
             var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
             {
                 ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                 ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                         (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => { return true; }
             };
             using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
             {
                 // Request data goes here
                 var scoreRequest = new
                 {
                     Inputs = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>()
                     {
                         {
                             "data",
                             new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
                             {
                                 new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                 {
                                     {
                                         "SaleDate", "2022-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "OfferingGroupId", "0"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "week_of_year", "7"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "month_of_year", "2"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "day_of_week", "1"
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                     {
                         {
                             "quantiles", "0.025,0.975"
                         }
                     }
                 };
    
    
                 const string apiKey = ""; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
                 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://4a0427c2-30d4-477e-85f5-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.uksouth.azurecontainer.io/score");
    
                 // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock
                 // if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                 // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false)
                 // so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                 // For instance, replace code such as:
                 //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                 // with the following:
                 //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)
    
                 var requestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scoreRequest);
                 var content = new StringContent(requestString);
    
                 content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    
                 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("", content);
    
                 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                 {
                     string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                     Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));
    
                     // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp,
                     // which are useful for debugging the failure
                     Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
    
                     string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                     Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                     Console.ReadLine();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Could you please help me with this issue? I am not sure what do to if Microsoft's provided code is erroring out, don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more digging I found out that the "Consume" scripts provided with the endpoint are wrong (Python and C#) .

When making a call to the endpoint the GlobalParameters expects an integer value, but the provided scripts have wrapped the values in double quotes hence making it a string:

```
 },
 "GlobalParameters": {
     "quantiles": "0.025,0.975"
 }
```

If you are using Python to consume the model, when making call to the endpoint your GlobalParameters should be define as this:

```
 },
 "GlobalParameters": {
     "quantiles": [0.025,0.975]
 }
```

wrapped in square brackets

> [0.025,0.975]

and not in double quotes "

> *I have also opened a ticket with microsoft so hopefully they will fix the code provided in the "consume" section of every endpoint*